# Retrofit @QUERY : If the field is null what is sent to the URL

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a question,
I have the following Retrofit post request

```
@POST("/user")
fun saveUser(@Body User)
```

The User class

```
data class User(val name: String? =null, val age:Int?=null)
```

If I call it like this

```
api.saveUser(User(null, 32))
```

Then what will the URL request looks like
This :

```
https://dummy.com/users?name=null&age=32
```

or:

```
https://dummy.com/users?name=&age=32
```

or:

```
https://dummy.com/users?age=32
```

Thank you very much. And if you could provide some evidence that would be great.

Comment: you should use `@GET`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will totally remove the query parameter, in your case it will be:

```
https://dummy.com/users?age=32
```

I am logging the request using `HttpLoggingInterceptor()` to check the url:

```
val builder = SslClientFactory.okHttpClientBuilder

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        builder.addInterceptor(logging)
    }

    return builder.build()
```

Comment: while this technically is definitely not a correct answer for the question, as in question parameters are not added as `@Query`, but as `@Body`, it still gave the answer to my question that I was searching for

Answer (score 1):

Uhm i don't think it's getting added to the query url. 
Your adding the user to the body of the request. 
So it will sent an JsonObject of user in the body like so:

```
{
  "name": null,
  "age" : 32
}
```

If I am correct.

It will only sent an post request to https://dummy.com/user <-- no query parameters are added. The body contains all the information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is correct, I found out the same through the docs. Sorry you are a bit late to be the accpeted answer :P

Comment: @adamyong you can still change it to be the accepted answer i hope.